# How to use bootstrap on Jquery easy ui

Tags: php, css, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

How do I use [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) on the [jQuery EasyUI framework](http://www.jeasyui.com/)?

When I try to include the CSS it always messes up my design.

Is it possible to include the CSS and the bootstrap js? If so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes its messed up because the 2 css stylesheets use the same selectors (some are the same).
What you would need to do, include both and choose which you want to rely on more.

Open up your css stylesheet and rename the selectors what match, or remove them if you dont need, thats all.

PS: buttons are messed up because of these too, example, the UI has a button css and js feature too and bootstap has one too, so they get mixed up

Comment: thanks i got my problem solved... thats right.. about selector

Answer (score 1):

Place your bootstrap folder in the themes folder

Include the bootstrap css directly below

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../themes/default/easyui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../themes/bootstrap/docs/assets/css/bootstrap.css">
```

If you need to include any other js files in the code you should include them at the end of the file.

```
<script src="/themes/bootstrap/docs/assets/js/application.js"></script>
<script src="/themes/bootstrap/docs/assets/js/bootstrap-affix.js"></script>
<script src="/themes/bootstrap/docs/assets/js/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
<script src="/themes/bootstrap/docs/assets/js/bootstrap-button.js"></script>
<script src="/themes/bootstrap/docs/assets/js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
<script src="/themes/bootstrap/docs/assets/js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
<script src="/themes/bootstrap/docs/assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
<script src="/themes/bootstrap/docs/assets/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
<script src="/themes/bootstrap/docs/assets/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
<script src="/themes/bootstrap/docs/assets/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>
<script src="/themes/bootstrap/docs/assets/js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
<script src="/themes/bootstrap/docs/assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
<script src="/themes/bootstrap/docs/assets/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
<script src="/themes/bootstrap/docs/assets/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>
<script src="/themes/bootstrap/docs/assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/themes/bootstrap/docs/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: when i insert that bootstrap my button messed up, any suggest??

Comment: May be it is using both the classes on the element of the 'button'. Either use class for 'bootstrap' or of 'easyui'